# Programmatically deploying portlets in locations through liferay?

Tags: java, portlet, liferay

I'd like to have a consistent layout every time I deploy my WAR, and currently, I need to manually move and add portlets to get the layout I need. Is there a way I can anagrammatically or through configuration setup liferay? Currently, the database isn't versioned, as I'm not sure there's a good way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [Layout](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout;jsessionid=38BA4B433971FF4E10861CA0415B9BDC.node-1), perhaps specified by a [Layout Template](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template).  These layouts can be part of a [Layout Set](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Set;jsessionid=38BA4B433971FF4E10861CA0415B9BDC.node-1) to create an entire portal.

To do this programmatically, you can follow the tutorial [here](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Programmatically+Create+a+Layout+and+Place+a+Content+Display+Portlet+on+it).  The class `LayoutLocalServiceUtil` is going to be key to the process.